# pandas - show N highest counts in a group-by dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

Here is my input DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
 ['CA', 'LAX', 'Alice'],
 ['NY', 'NYC', 'Alice'],
 ['TX', 'HOU', 'Alice'],
 ['CA', 'SFO', 'Bob'], 
 ['NY', 'NYC', 'Bob'],
 ['TX', 'AUS', 'Bob'], 
 ['CA', 'LAX', 'Carol'],
 ['NY', 'ALB', 'Carol'], 
 ['TX', 'HOU', 'Carol'],
 ['CA', 'LAX', 'Dan'],
 ['NY', 'NYC', 'Dan'],
 ['TX', 'DAL', 'Dan'],
 ['CA', 'SFO', 'Eve'],
 ['NY', 'NYC', 'Eve'],
 ['TX', 'AUS', 'Eve'], 
 ['CA', 'SDO', 'Frank'],
 ['NY', 'NYC', 'Frank'],
 ['TX', 'HOU', 'Frank']], 
 columns=['State','City','Person'])
```

And here is the output I wish to get:

```
State City  Count       
CA    LAX    3
      SFO    2
NY    ALB    1
      NYC    5
TX    HOU    3
      AUS    2
```

**Basically, I want to show the top 2 cities having the highest count of people, for each state.**

I have tried using this groupby statement:
`df.groupby(['State','City'])['Person'].count()`

which generates below output

```
State  City         
CA     LAX    3
       SDO    1
       SFO    2
NY     ALB    1
       NYC    5
TX     AUS    2
       DAL    1
       HOU    3
```

But I am unable to come up with statements which could sort the above counts and pick the highest two counts. Would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simplify the approach.

You can use `groupby.value_counts()`, instead of `count()`, to get where you are, and then chain another `groupby().head(2)` to get the top 2 Cities per each state.

The reason is that [`value_counts()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-index-value_counts/#:%7E:text=value_counts()%20function%20returns%20object,Excludes%20NA%20values%20by%20default.) resulting object will be in `descending` order, so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element, so you can use `head(2)` as it is.

```
df.groupby('State')['City'].value_counts().groupby('State').head(2)

State  City
CA     LAX     3
       SFO     2
NY     NYC     5
       ALB     1
TX     HOU     3
       AUS     2
Name: City, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was thinking about `value_counts` as well, don't know why I didn't follow through, nice solution 

Answer (score 2):

Your first groupby was correct, after that you want to sort your values based on State and Count.

Then you group again solely on the state and fetch the head(2). If you want, you can (re)set your index to State and City.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['State','City'])['Person'].count().to_frame('Count')
df2 = df2.reset_index().sort_values(['State', 'Count'], ascending=[True, False])

df2.groupby('State').head(2).set_index(['State','City'])
```

Output:

```
                Count
State   City    
CA      LAX     3
        SFO     2
NY      NYC     5
        ALB     1
TX      HOU     3
        AUS     2
```